# Consume remote api with jwt-webtoken & request

Tags: node.js, jwt, node-request

I've created an api following this example: https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode (except I use mysql). It's working all fine when I test it via postman.

Now ... I want to know how OTHERS can properly use/consume this api. What I have so far is:

So I have two request ... the first gets the token:

### First Request

```
const request = require("request");

request.post({
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:2001/abc/login",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: "test@abc.it",
        password: "sisw9234&"
    })
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(body).token);
});
```

... the second ... when I replace myToken with the actual token ... provides me the requested json:

### Second Request

```
const request = require("request");

var token = 'myToken';
var auth = 'Bearer '+token;

request.get({
    headers: {
        "authorization": auth
    },  
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:2001/abc/search?name=peter"
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

How do I properly combine them?

In addition ... the token is as of right now only valid for 360s. What's the best way to handle this situation ... duration of valid token, login, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) After getting the token, you should save it into memory, REDIS, session, ... based on your business logic. After that, when calling the other API, you can get it back from where you have saved.

For example,

- If the token is related to each of user, you should save it to the session. With express server, you can use `npm install express-session`.
- If It is used for your application to call other service, every request use the same token, you can save into memory: `global.GLOBAL_TOKEN = response.token`
- If you run multiple instance, then you need to save it on a distributed cache like REDIS

2) About token expired, The best practice of OAuth is that when you logged in, the server always response one more token (long-term token, refresh token or whatever you call it). You can use that refresh token to get new token.

In case, you don't have that kind of token, you need to save the username, password the same way you save the token to login again to get the new token.

About checking the expire token. You can use `JWT.decode`, which doesn't require the secret to decode. By doing that, you can get the time that the token is expired. the key for checking usually are `exp` or `iat`.

More information about JWT can be found in https://jwt.io/

Example with express session

```
app.use(session({ secret: 'some-secret-here', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// login endpoint
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    request.post({
        headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:2001/abc/login",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password
        })
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
             res.write('login failed');
             return res.end();
        }
        // save token to session
        req.session.token = JSON.parse(body).token;
        res.write('login success');
        return res.end();
    });
});

// endpoint need token endpoint
app.get('something', (req, res) => {
    // use token to call the other things here 
    var token = req.session.token;
    res.write('your token ' + token);
    return res.end();
});
```

Example using localStorage on clientside:

const request = require("request");

```
request.post({
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:2001/abc/login",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: "test@abc.it",
        password: "sisw9234&"
    })
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var token = JSON.parse(body).token;
    localStorage.setItem("USER_TOKEN", token);
});
```

Second request

```
const request = require("request");

var token = localStorage.getItem('USER_TOKEN');
var auth = 'Bearer '+token;

request.get({
    headers: {
        "authorization": auth
    },  
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:2001/abc/search?name=peter"
}, (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes ... the generated token is related to each user ... and I‘m using express in this application. So I can add express-session. But I‘m also struggling how the could then shoulde look like. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I also provided an update to my questions. To be more precise: I followed this tutorial https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode  (except I'm using mysql) ... everything is working ... and my question now is in regards to how OTHERS can now consume/use this api. Does your example reflect this?

Comment: If you are using client side App (like REACT) to consume the API. The you just need to save the token in cookie or local storage, and get it back for other API. The way to check expired JWT is the same flow in client side.

Answer (score 1):

I think the token is not signed properly in the backend.

The right usage of JWT.sign is

`jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])`

```
signToken = user => {
  return JWT.sign({
    iss: 'CodeWorkr',
    sub: user.id,
    iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
    // exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time +     1 day ahead
  }, JWT_SECRET, {
     expiresIn: 3600 // 1 hr = 3600s
  });
}
```

As you can see you should pass `expiresIn` option after JWT_SECRET not `exp` in the payload(to avoid day calculations).

If you want to verify if the token is expired, the only way is to verify it in the server side.

To use this token again, you need to save it to `localStorage` and use it whenever needed.

```
localStorage.setItem('token', token)
const token = localStorage.getItem('token') // use this token
```

Comment: I do have a token based authentication. See example here: https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode. My question now is in regard to how OTHERS can consume it now. Your example doesn't mention the token ... why?

Comment: @PhilippM . I think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: The expiration(duration) of the token should be adjusted in the login function.https://github.com/eXtremeXR/APIAuthenticationWithNode/blob/master/server/controllers/users.js#L10

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your first request gets a token from your server which you then use on the second request for the purposes of searching for peter, and you want to combine these requests.

The [standard practice](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52) for this sort of thing is keeping the requests separate as you have, so I would advise against combining them.

Regarding the token only being valid for 360s, I assume you have access to the server code because you are sending requests to localhost, so you need to modify the expiration of the token there.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation ... could you also provide code to it?